# MySql Query with a left join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

so I have a query I'm working on that I can't get it to do what I'd like. I need it to return all the parts that make up an product and if it has a partLotNumber associated with it in a completed order I'd like to get that in another column (IE a left join). I can get my query to get all the parts that make up a product, and i can get all the partlotnumbers in a completed product but I cannot get it to do both. All my attempts so far output every part with every partLotNumber.

this query returns all the parts that make up a product

```
SELECT orders.orderNumber, orderline.orderlineID, products.productID, assembly.assemblyID, assemblyparts.partID, parts.name
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN orderline ON orders.orderNumber = orderline.orderNumber
LEFT JOIN products ON orderline.productID = products.productID
LEFT JOIN assemblyproduct ON products.productID = assemblyproduct.productID
LEFT JOIN assembly ON assemblyproduct.assemblyID = assembly.assemblyID
INNER JOIN assemblyparts ON assemblyproduct.assemblyID = assemblyparts.assemblyID
LEFT JOIN parts ON assemblyparts.partID = parts.partID
WHERE orders.orderNumber = 1024
```

and this query returns all the parts of a finished product.

```
SELECT orders.orderNumber, orderline.orderlineID,  products.productNumber, assemblyproduct.assemblyID, lotrecord.finishedLotNumber, assemblylot.assemblyLotNumber, assemblyline.assemblylineID, assemblyline.partLotNumber, parts.name
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN orderline ON orders.orderNumber = orderline.orderNumber
LEFT JOIN products ON orderline.productID = products.productID
LEFT JOIN assemblyproduct ON products.productID = assemblyproduct.productID
LEFT JOIN assembly ON assemblyproduct.assemblyID = assembly.assemblyID
LEFT JOIN lotrecord ON products.productID = lotrecord.productID
LEFT JOIN finishedlotinventory ON lotrecord.finishedLotNumber = finishedlotinventory.finishedLotNumber
LEFT JOIN assemblylot ON finishedlotinventory.assemblyLotNumber = assemblylot.assemblyLotNumber
LEFT JOIN assemblyline ON assemblylot.assemblyLotNumber = assemblyline.assemblyLotNumber
LEFT JOIN inventory ON assemblyline.partLotNumber = inventory.partLotNumber
LEFT JOIN parts ON inventory.partID = parts.partID
WHERE orders.orderNumber = '1038'
```

basically what I want to be able to do is select an order number, it returns all the orderlines, the product in that orderline, and then the assemblies that make up that product, and then the parts that make up the assembly, and if it has been submitted to the assemblyline table I want to return the partLotNumber associated with that order. So far I can only get completed orders to show, I can't get incomplete ones.

here is a pic of my db diagram, some tables omitted for reading clarity. 
[image: database diagram]

Comment: can you post your schema to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? and maybe provide some sample data to work with? It would be much easier...

Comment: The two queries that you show, do they work?

Comment: @cenk I am uploading now

Comment: @PM yes they work for each portion

Comment: @cenk, I can't post to sqlfiddle, the database schema is too large